# how to remove characters between /* */ in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

I want remove characters between /**/ from a string

example:

convert the string

> "select * from food where /* id = 1 and */ food_code = 2"

to

> "select * from food where  food_code = 2"

Answer (score 0):

It could be done like this

```
select regexp_replace('select * from food where /* id = 1 and */ food_code = 2', '\/\*.+\*\/', '','g');
```

Escaping '/' and '*'.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a positive lookbehind `(?<=re)` and positive lookahead `(?=re)`

This will capture and remove multiple /*.+*/

```
select regexp_replace(string, '\/\*(?<=\/\*)(.*?)(?=\*\/)\*\/','', 'g')
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1CjI4Cqs)

Comment: sorry!!! when use this string 'select * from food where /* id = /1 and */ food_code = 2' , your code not working

Comment: this string not work for me 'select * from food where /* id/* = *//1 and */ food_code = 2 /*work*/ and id =4'

Comment: So you need whenever between first /* and last */ to be removed ?

Comment: i want string 'select * from food where /* id/* = *//1 and */ food_code = 2 /*work*/ and id =4' to string 'select * from food where  food_code = 2 and id =4' , Only the codes inside /*...*/ should be removed

Comment: This code "select regexp_replace('select * from food where /* id = 1 and */ food_code = 2 /*work*/ and id =4', '\/\*[^*/]+\*\/','','g')" you sent earlier was correct, it only had a problem with the / character

Comment: "So you need whenever between first /* and last */ to be removed ?" : Yes, exactly

Comment: This is great, but there is one problem:
This will convert the sample "select * from food where /* id = /*work*/1 and */ food_code = 2 /*work*/ and id =4" to this "select * from food where 1 and */ food_code = 2  and id =4 ".